# Is there a way to email specific powershell results

Tags: powershell

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName (Get-Content 'C:\xxxxx\xxxxx.txt') -ErrorAction Continue -Count 1
```

I currently use the above command to test connections on sevreal remote PCs. It's basic and does the job, however i am looking to automate this and where i get stuck is how to filter only the failed connections from the result and output them as an email?

Thanks

really unsure how to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$unreachables = Get-Content 'C:\xxxxx\xxxxx.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        # output the failed machines
        $_
    }
}
if (@($unreachables).Count) {
    # create a Hashtable with parameters used for splatting to Send-MailMessage
    # something like this
    $mailParams = @{
        From       = 'me@contoso.com'
        To         = 'mycolleague@contoso.com'
        Subject    = "unreachable computers"
        SmtpServer = 'mail.contoso.com'
        Body       = "The following computers are off-line ({0}):`r`n`r`n{1}" -f (Get-Date), ($unreachables -join "`r`n")
    }
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams
}
else {
    Write-Host 'All tested computers are online'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Could you kindly clarify line 2?   -ComputerName 'suske','lambiek'

Comment: @oceanblu Sorry, those were some test servers I used and forgot to take that out. I have updated my answer in the meantime.

Comment: Hi Theo, I got around to testing this, however, it's not outputting any email. I tried adding -Credential (Get-Credential) to the script, as I thought perhaps it needs to authenticate the sender. it prompted for a username and password and authenticated successfully but no email

Comment: @oceanblu Well, I do not know the specifics of your mail server, but you probably also need to specify the `Port` number and/or add  `UseSsl = $true` to the mailParams. Have a look at the docs for [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage)